# python: Use part of dict key as variable for dict value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary that looks like this:

```
mapper = {
    "bigint(20)": "= Column(BigInteger)",
    "int(11)": "= Column(Integer)",
    "`": "",
    "varchar(255)": "= Column(String)",
}
```

I am mapping sql datatype naming into sqlalchemy-like to be replaced into a text file. So far I am just mapping int to integer, varchar to string and so on. However, my idea is to use part of the key as variable to be passed to its relative value, i.e. avoiding to hardcode `varchar(255)` and use `varchar(x)` to be passed to its relative value `= Column(String())` having `= Column(String(x))`.

Something like:

```
"varchar(x)": "= Column(String{})".format(x),
```

Do you have any suggestions how to achieve that? thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand but it could just be me..

Comment: Can you provide an example of input data, and what you want to achieve (It look like you just need to write a function that finds 'varchar', extract the following parenthesis and replace with 'Column(String{})'.format(value) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `dict` is a fixed set of concrete keys; you cannot do what you want with a `dict` alone.

However, you can subclass `dict` to provide a definition of `__getitem__` that can do what you want. Something like

```
import re
class SQLDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        m = re.match('^varchar\((.*)\)$', key)
        if m:
            return super(SQLDict, self).__getitem__('varchar(x)') % (m.group(1),)
        else:
            return super(SQLDIct,self).__getitem__(key)

mapper = SQLDict({
    "bigint(20)": "= Column(BigInteger)",
    "int(11)": "= Column(Integer)",
    "`": "",
    "varchar(x)": "= Column(String(%s))",
})
```

Trying it out...

```
>>> print mapper['varchar(15)']
'=Column(String(215))'
```

It's not perfect; I've hard-coded `varchar(x)` into the definition of `__getitem__`, while you might define `mapper` to have a key like `varchar(y)` instead. But this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you. This should get me started!